# Import C++ DLL Library in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, visual-c++, dll

I'm quite new with this topic, so please forgive me some dummy questions.

The main idea is import in VBA (for example Excel) a DLL compiled from C++. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 for the DLL. I followed the guided tool and I have created the following files:

```
//KingFunc.h
#pragma once
namespace KingFuncs
{
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int GiveMeNumber(int i);

}
```

Then .cpp

```
//KingFunc.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "KingFunc.h"
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

namespace KingFuncs
{
    int KingFuncs::GiveMeNumber(int i)
{
    return i;
}
}
```

The compiler gives apparently no errors and produces a DLL output, named KingFunc.dll in the project folder.

Then I opened Excel --> VBA tool and wrote the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare Function PASS Lib _
"[PATH]\KingFunc.dll" (x As Integer) As Integer

Sub MAIN()
     Dim a As Integer
     Dim b As Integer

     a = 100
     b = PASS(a)

End Sub
```

where PATH is the long folder string of VS project.

I'd expect it works, but it does not... "It is not possible to find the file" I don't understand why.

I also tried to set the VBA calling as

```
Public Declare Function PASS Lib _
"[PATH]\KingFunc.dll" Alias "GiveMeNumber" (x As Integer) As Integer
```

Comment: This is how I add C# library to VBA - http://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-add-a-c-library-to-a-vba-project/ In C++ it could be something similar, if you use Visual Studio for IDE. (will remove if it is considered spam)

Comment: No. It is not a spam... I did not see this link.

Comment: There are some limits to what VBA can support.  This [MS doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687915.aspx) highlights quite a few.